# Can I scroll a fragment in and out of an activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll

I have a Fragment which i want to scroll in and out of an Acitvity. 
Right know i have an onScroll event which when it is called finds out the direction and then moves the fragment in this direction. But this way it is like the scroll method is only triggering the moveUp (or down) methods for my fragment which looks very stiff. I would like to have nice animation like when you scroll a list or so... Has anyone done this before? Or has an idea how to translate a fragment in sync with the scrolling?

Comment: The reason you can't put it in a scrollview is... ?

Comment: @ SnyersK 3 I want what is in my fragment to disappear! You can always see the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but with an OnTouchListener you can detect every movement while touching the view. I think the event that you get has a x and y value for the movement that you are doing. maybe these can be used to move your fragment

Answer (score 0):

Create a LinearLayout set its y position to bottom of screen so that is not visible. Load you fragment in this linearLayout and set a **onTouchListener** event. See following code:

```
parentLyoutOfPage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        private int initialY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            switch(arg1.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialY = (int) arg0.getY();

                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                flag = false;
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                move(fragmentContainer,(int) arg1.getRawY()); // Method to move LinearLayout that contains Fragment. Create animation objects that swipes in and out to animate it after a threshold value of ACTION_UP.

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Above code is just for reference. you have to modify it to make it working.

Comment: the event is not the problem. onFling doesn´t look better than scroll... What I have troubles with is what to do in the event function. And I don´t want to replace a fragment, i want to change it´s position.

Comment: Changing position of Fragment is not giving me clear picture of what you want to do. Are you trying to put fragments in scrollView or what?

Comment: I want to build something like a navDrawer just from the button. So when I start the Activity i can´t see the fragment but when I scroll in a cirtain direction I should be able to pull it out like in the nav drawer

Comment: If you want it to be like navigation drawer, why are you not using NavigationDrawer it self?

Comment: I tried but you can´t place the navigation Drawer at the bottom of the phone which I want. So I have to build one myself unless you know how to put the nav drawer at the bottom...